# Bash Select Formatting

Tags: bash, jq

I have setup a script I can run to connect to my servers, which are contained in a json string variable.

While the script works just fine, I am finding that I do not really care too much for the `select` output as it shows me the entire row.   What I would like to do is simply display the `server` yet still return the `ip` and `user`.

Is this possible?  If so, how?    Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

_key="/home/MyUser/Documents/Keys/MyKey.pem"

# our server json
_servers='[{"server":"server1","ip":"10.0.0.1","user":"root"},{"server":"server2","ip":"10.0.0.2","user":"ubuntu"},{"server":"server3","ip":"192.168.4.112","user":"ec2-user"}]';


# loop over the items and display the server
echo "- Select a server to connect to: "
select _t in $(echo ${_servers} | jq -c '.[]'); do

    # will keep asking until valid value given
    [ -n "$_t" ] && break
done

# parse the selected row
_server=$(echo $_t | jq '.server');
_ip=$(echo $_t | jq '.ip');
_user=$(echo $_t | jq '.user');

echo "Connnecting to: ${_server:1:-1}";
sleep 2

#echo ${_ip:1:-1}
#echo ${_user:1:-1}

# make the connection
ssh -i $_key ${_user:1:-1}@${_ip:1:-1}
```

the select currently shows me:

```
me@MyMachine:~/Desktop# bash test
- Select a server to connect to: 
1) {"server":"server1","ip":"10.0.0.1","user":"root"}
2) {"server":"server2","ip":"10.0.0.2","user":"ubuntu"}
3) {"server":"server3","ip":"192.168.4.112","user":"ec2-user"}
#?
```

And what I would like it to show instead:

```
me@MyMachine:~/Desktop# bash test
- Select a server to connect to: 
1) server1
2) server2
3) server3
#?
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to parse the information you are printing before printing it. Something like: `x=$(echo "${_server:1:-1}" | tr "," "\\t" | awk '{ print $1 }' | tr ":" "\\t" | awk '{ print $1 }') ; echo "Connecting to: $x"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an associative array that maps a server name to the JSON object representing that server.

```
declare -A servers
while read -r name data; do
    servers[$name]=$data
done < <(jq -rc '.[] | "\(.server) \(.)"' <<< "$_servers")
```

Then you'll select a server name, and process the associate data after the `select` statement.

```
select _t in "${!servers[@]}"; do
    [ -n "$_t" ] && break
done

read _server _ip _user < <(jq -rc '[.server, .ip, .user][]' <<< "${servers[$_t]}"
```

---

Alternatively, process the JSON once and store the IP addresses and user names in separate arrays.

```
declare -A ips users
while read -r _server _ip _user; do
    ips[$_server]=$_ip
    users[$_server]=$_user
done < <(jq -rc '.[] | "\(.server) \(.ip) \(.user)"' <<< "$_servers")

select _server in "${!ips[@]}"; do  # could use "${!users[@]}" as well
  [ -n "$_server" ] && break
done

_ip=${ips[$_server]}
_user=${users[$_user]}
```

Comment: `test: line 11: ips[$server]: bad array subscript`

Comment: Fixed; forgot some underscores.

Comment: changed.   had to change `_user=${users[$_server]}` as well, (bad array subscript), however, when I echo `$_ip` and `$_user` under those 2 lines, nothing is shown

Comment: got it.   in the `while` block, just add an underscore to `=$ip` and `=$user`

Comment: OK, I think I've fixed all the variable  names now.